# set proxy value in only current shell temporary

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, proxy, playonlinux

I have a question reagrding setting proxy value in a unix OS.
I want to apply the proxy setting for current on going shell temporarily and should not affect the system wide proxy settings because i use another value there.

I am running below command

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=abc.com:9900
newman run <command goes on> //npm command
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

but this unsets the whole system proxy as well.
any clue how to execute this in current shell as only kind of local environment

Answer (score 3):

You can exec command like:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=abc.com:9900 newman run <command goes on> //npm command
```

and this will set the variable only for this run of the process

Comment: Doesnt really works :-( still gives error of error tunnelling socket

Comment: @Alex, the problem is in your config, run parameters. This is the way in UNIX/Linux to set variable temporary

Comment: after I ran this command I also ran echo $HTTPS_PROXY it showed me blank

Comment: @Alex, as I explain in my answer the set of this variable is ONLY for this execution of the software.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that HTTPS_PROXY variable is probably set at boot time, so when you clear it with

```
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

it won't be populated any more until you reboot (or possibily do a logout/login).

An easy solution would be to save the *current* value in a temporary variable and then restore it when done, i.e.:

```
export TMP_HTTPS=$HTTPS_PROXY
export HTTPS_PROXY=abc.com:9900
newman run <command goes on> //npm command
export HTTPS_PROXY=$TMP_HTTPS
unset TMP_HTTPS
```

As this is quite tedious to do every time, a better solution would be to add the
variable with the correct *global* proxy to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.
This way every time you open a new shell you will have the correct one.

This has the disadvantage of possibily creating conflicts.

Another solution would be to create a bash *function* with a local override of the `HTTPS_PROXY` variable (as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393928/global-local-variable-assignment)). Something like:

```
my_custom_newman() {
    local HTTPS_PROXY=abc.com:9900
    newman run <command goes on> //npm command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `export` and `unset` [builtins](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html) (not commands) are only affecting the current instance of bash and its children!

The `$HTTPS_PROXY` variable is typically set via `/etc/environment` (hole system) or locally in `~/.bashrc`. If your system has a always set proxy variable you can modify it in the current shell or sub-shell:

```
# Show current proxy settings
$ echo proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY
proxy=http://localhost:3128/

# Proxy setting in new shell (important use singel quotes):
$ bash -c 'echo proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY'
proxy=http://localhost:3128/

# Unset proxy in new shell:
$ bash -c 'unset HTTPS_PROXY; echo proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY'
proxy=
```

So your system is **not affected** by `export` or `unset` in your current shell.

As suggested in the other answer, you can always modify shell variables per command and most tools will not use the proxy settings, if `$HTTP(S)_PROXY` is empty:

```
# Empty proxy variable for bash command
$ HTTPS_PROXY= bash -c 'echo proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY'
proxy=

# Or clear all proxy variables
HTTP_PROXY= HTTPS_PROXY= bash -c 'echo proxy=$HTTPS_PROXY'
proxy=
```